# Initialize an array of objects

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Enemy {
  public:
  int life;
  int damage;
  bool living;
  int enemies;


  

  void takeDamage() {
    if (living) {
    }
  }

  Enemy (int dp, int hp) {
    damage = dp;
    life = hp;
  }

};

class Hero {
  public:
  int life;
  int damage;
  bool living;

  void takeDamage() {
    if (living) {

    }
  }

  Hero (int dp, int num) {
    damage = dp;
  }

};

int main() {
  int enemies;
  int enemyDamage;
  int heroHP;
  int heroDP;

  cout << "Enter the number of enemies: ";
  cin >> enemies;
  cout << "Enter the enemy damage: ";
  cin >> enemyDamage;
  cout << "Enter the hero's starting HP: ";
  cin >> heroHP;
  cout << "Enter the hero's damage: ";
  cin >> heroDP;

  int enemyArray[enemies];

  for (int i = 0; i < enemies; i++) {
    enemyArray[i] = 10 + (2*i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < enemies; i++) {
    Enemy enemyArray[i] (enemyDamage,enemyArray[i]);
  }
}
```

I am working on an assignment where I have a hero class that "fights" an array of enemies. The user inputs the number of enemies and the health and damage dealt. I need to have the enemies in an array but am unsure how to do that with a class. Please let me know if unclear.

Comment: You will find [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) easier to wrangle than an array. Arrays are really, really limited. For example, `int enemyArray[enemies];` is only legal by non-Standard extensions present in only a few compilers

Comment: You should use something like `std::vector<Enemy> enemyArray(enemies);`

Comment: Unfortunately this is for an assignment where we are required to use an array.

Comment: @JustinWilker Well, you'll need to do the memory management yourself then, using `new Enemy[enemies]` and `delete []`.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  You've only told a story about how you don't know how to store an array of `Enemy`.  Did you try it?  Was there an error?  If you tried it correctly, there would have been an error.  Your subsequent code is illegal, and I can only guess that you tried something more crazy after not understanding the error.  Hint: your class must provide a default constructor.

Comment: @paddy My question is how to initialize an array of objects. I have tried it myself and in my final for loop I get the error "array initializer must be an initializer list". What do you mean by mu subsequent code is illegal?

Comment: Unfortunate. One of the things you can't do with an array is easy initialization. If you know all of the enemies and statistics at compile time you can use [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), but if you need to read them from a file or otherwise don't know the statistics until runtime, you need a default constructor and then assignments. (or [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), but that's probably overkill)

Comment: `Enemy enemyArray[i] (enemyDamage,enemyArray[i]);` is broken in several ways. `Enemy enemyArray[i]` makes a new array of `Enemy`s of size `i`. It also replaces the previously defined `enemyArray`, so `enemyArray[i]` doesn't refer to the `int` array, it refers to the `i`th element of the brand new array. Which doesn't have an `i`th element because it's only valid between 0 and `i-1`.

Comment: A suggestion: it may be easier to write your own simple vector-like class that lets you do what you want rather than mess around with raw arrays. Not only will you learn a lot more, you'll have a tool you can keep using until your instructor lets you really start programming in C++. You can find many examples of simple vector substitutes  scattered around Stack overflow and it's companion site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)